# Meaning of "Cassandra provides atomicity and isolation when targeting a single partition for batch mutations"

Tags: cassandra

Assume the following:

1. My batch statements belongs to a single partition
2. Requested consistency of the write is Quorum
3. Replication factor is 3

Q. Does that mean it will not be visible for reads (i.e isolation) with consistency 1 until the write is confirmed in all replicas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddaccql/doc/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html

> All replicas for the single partition receive the data, and the coordinator waits for acknowledgement.

A write consistency of `QUORUM` is irrelevant here.  Data will not be available for reads at *any* consistency level until the write is confirmed (batch completes).  In other words, there shouldn't be a time period where reads @ consistency `ONE` might fail after a BATCH operation.

Comment: well. I found this where you set the consistency level to batch statement. ```batchStatement.setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.valueOf(serialConsistencyLevel));
```. So how does it achieves isolation for the batch unless it locks all replicas for that partition?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Serial consistency on a BATCH statement is not a true write consistency level.  Notice that there isn't a `setQuorumConsistency` method.  In fact, it is an isolation level that derives completion consensus via Paxos.